# node.js command line file excel on web server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, web-services

My script in node.js generate a excel file, I need to put this file available on web server like web url and people can download it directly. Right now, script generate a excel file and it is available in windows folder. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use nodejs for this you can use something like "static-server" and create a server that will export everything from you'r folder to the "web".. 
But much better approach is to do it throught nginx or apache.

You can google with keywords "static [file] server (nginx|apache|nodejs)".